# Dynamically add views to a recycleview.viewholder

Tags: android, xamarin, android-recyclerview

I want to add views dynamically to my recycleview viewholder, in my viewholder i currently do this:

```
public void CreateSubViews()
    {

        SubViewLayout.RemoveAllViews ();
        if (_bundelVo.OverviewTocList != null) 
        {       
                int i = 0;
                DSBundleSubView sub;
                foreach (var toc in _bundelVo.OverviewTocList) 
                {
                    sub = new DSBundleSubView (_activity);
                    SubViewLayout.AddView (sub);
                    sub.SetTocData (_bundelVo, _bundelVo.OverviewTocList [i]);
                    i++;
                }
        } 
    }
```

I call this method in the adapter inside OnBindViewHolder(). Subviewlayout is just a vertical linearlayout that i hold in the viewholder to add the views

The subviews are not generated, i think this is because the layoutmanager calculates the size of each viewholder in the recyclerview.

How do i create a custom layoutmanager so that i can see the views that are added to a viewholder item or how can i achieve this ?

Comment: Can you post your whole viewholder code? Also, are you trying to dynamically expand each viewholder depending on the amount of subitems in the item? Typically I inflate the view in OnCreateViewHolder and then just update the view data in OnBindViewHolder.

Comment: +1 I am facing a similar issue. Have to do a removeAllViews and then add textviews dynamiclly. Ends up with jittery UI

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of how the output looks?